# getting duplicate objects in json in android

Tags: android, json

I am putting objects in Json but I want only 1 key to be update.Right now it is creating new object every time function is called I want only quantity should get updated if it is already there in json. Please help

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

private List<ProductBean> productList ;

static int qtyValues;
static int itemRem = -1;
static int addItem = 1;
static boolean isSKU1;
static boolean isSKU2;
static boolean isSKU;
static int value;
static int totalAmount = 0;
static int totalItems = 0;
SharedPreferences myPrefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private final Activity context;
private AQuery aq;


JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray();
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

public ProductAdapter(Activity context,List<ProductBean> productList){
    this.productList = productList;
    this.context = context;
    isSKU = true;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productList.size();
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("qty", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = myPrefs.edit();
    aq = new AQuery(context.getApplicationContext());

    final ProductBean productBean = productList.get(position);

    holder.extratxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.extratxt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.extratxt2.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            holder.extratxt3.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            holder.extratxt1.setText(productBean.getProductPrice() + "");
            isSKU = true;
            isSKU1 = false;
            isSKU2 = false;
            holder.qtyCounter.setText(myPrefs.getInt("product"+productBean.getProductId()+productBean.getSkuId1(),0)+"");
        }
    });

    holder.extratxt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.extratxt.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            holder.extratxt2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.extratxt3.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            holder.extratxt1.setText(productBean.getProductPrice2() + "");
            isSKU1 = true;
            isSKU = false;
            isSKU2 = false;
            holder.qtyCounter.setText(myPrefs.getInt("product"+productBean.getProductId()+productBean.getSkuId2(),0)+"");
        }
    });
    holder.extratxt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.extratxt.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            holder.extratxt2.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            holder.extratxt3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.extratxt1.setText(productBean.getProductPrice3() + "");
            isSKU2 = true;
            isSKU = false;
            isSKU1 = false;
            holder.qtyCounter.setText(myPrefs.getInt("product"+productBean.getProductId()+productBean.getSkuId3(),0)+"");
        }
    });

    holder.decreaseQty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            if(isSKU1 == true) {
                    if(myPrefs.getInt("product"+productBean.getProductId()+productBean.getSkuId2(),0)>0) {
                        qtyValues = myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId2(), 0);
                        qtyValues = qtyValues - 1;
                        editor.putInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId2(), qtyValues);
                        editor.commit();
                        holder.qtyCounter.setText(myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId2(), 0) + "");
                        value = 0 - productBean.getProductPrice2();
                        add(itemRem);
                        amount(value);
                    }
                }
                else if (isSKU2 == true){
                    if(myPrefs.getInt("product"+productBean.getProductId()+productBean.getSkuId3(),0)>0) {
                        qtyValues = myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId3(), 0);
                        qtyValues = qtyValues - 1;
                        editor.putInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId3(), qtyValues);
                        editor.commit();
                        holder.qtyCounter.setText(myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId3(), 0) + "");
                        value = 0 - productBean.getProductPrice3();
                        add(itemRem);
                        amount(value);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(myPrefs.getInt("product"+productBean.getProductId()+productBean.getSkuId1(),0)>0) {
                        qtyValues = myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId1(), 0);
                        qtyValues = qtyValues - 1;
                        editor.putInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId1(), qtyValues);
                        editor.commit();
                        holder.qtyCounter.setText(myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId1(), 0) + "");
                        value = 0 - productBean.getProductPrice();
                        add(itemRem);
                        amount(value);
                    }
                }
            }
    });
    holder.increaseQty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
                if(isSKU1 == true) {
                    if(myPrefs.getInt("product"+productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId2(),0)<10) {
                        qtyValues = myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId2(), 0);
                        qtyValues = qtyValues + 1;
                        editor.putInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId2(), qtyValues);
                        editor.commit();
                        holder.qtyCounter.setText(myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId2(), 0) + "");
                        value = productBean.getProductPrice2();
                        add(addItem);
                        amount(value);
                        setCartItem(productBean.getSkuId2(),myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId2(), 0),productBean.getProductId(),productBean.getDescription() , productBean.getProductName() , productBean.getProductPrice2());
                    }
                }
                else if (isSKU2 == true){
                    if(myPrefs.getInt("product"+productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId3(),0)<10) {
                        qtyValues = myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId3(), 0);
                        qtyValues = qtyValues + 1;
                        editor.putInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId3(), qtyValues);
                        editor.commit();
                        holder.qtyCounter.setText(myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId3(), 0) + "");
                        value = productBean.getProductPrice3();
                        add(addItem);
                        amount(value);
                        setCartItem(productBean.getSkuId3(),myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId3(), 0),productBean.getProductId(),productBean.getDescription() , productBean.getProductName() , productBean.getProductPrice3());
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(myPrefs.getInt("product"+productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId1(),0)<10) {
                        qtyValues = myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId1(), 0);
                        qtyValues = qtyValues + 1;
                        editor.putInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId1(), qtyValues);
                        editor.commit();
                        holder.qtyCounter.setText(myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId1(), 0) + "");
                        value = productBean.getProductPrice();
                        add(addItem);
                        amount(value);
                        setCartItem(productBean.getSkuId1(),myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId1(), 0),productBean.getProductId(),productBean.getDescription() , productBean.getProductName() , productBean.getProductPrice());
                    }
                }
        }
    });

    holder.txtTitle.setText(productBean.getProductName());
    holder.extratxt.setText(productBean.getSkuId1() + "");
    holder.extratxt2.setText(productBean.getSkuId2() + "");
    holder.extratxt3.setText(productBean.getSkuId3() + "");
    holder.extratxt1.setText(productBean.getProductPrice() + "");
    holder.imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.rupee);
    if(myPrefs.getInt("totalItems", 0)>0){
        BeveragesMainActivity.cartTotal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        BeveragesMainActivity.totalPrice.setText("Rs " + myPrefs.getInt("totalAmount", 0) + "");
    }
    BeveragesMainActivity.cartTotal.setText(myPrefs.getInt("totalItems", 0) + "");
    holder.qtyCounter.setText(myPrefs.getInt("product"+productBean.getProductId()+productBean.getSkuId1(),0) + "");
}



@Override
public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_beverages_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new ProductViewHolder(itemView);
}

public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView extratxt;
    TextView extratxt2;
    TextView extratxt3;
    ImageView imageView1;
    TextView extratxt1;
    TextView qtyCounter;
    ImageView decreaseQty;
    ImageView increaseQty;


    /**
     * Instantiates a new card view holder.
     *
     * @param v the v
     */
    public ProductViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.drinks);
        txtTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.drinkTitle);
        extratxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.drinkQuantity);
        extratxt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.drinkQuantity1);
        extratxt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.drinkQuantity2);
        imageView1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.rupee);
        extratxt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.drinkPrice);
        qtyCounter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.drinkCounter);
        decreaseQty = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.decreaseCounter);
        increaseQty = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.increaseCounter);
        extratxt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }


}

public void setCartItem(final int skuId ,final int qty , final long productId , String description , String productName , int price) {

    try {

        jsonObject.put("skuId",skuId);
        jsonObject.put("quantity",qty);
        jsonObject.put("productId",productId);
        jsonObject.put("price",price);
        jsonObject.put("productName",productName);
        jsonObject.put("description",description);

        obj.put(jsonObject);
        editor.putString("data",obj.toString());
        editor.commit();
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }        
}


public void add(int items){
    totalItems = totalItems + items;
    editor.putInt("totalItems",totalItems);
    editor.commit();
    if(myPrefs.getInt("totalItems", 0)>0){
        BeveragesMainActivity.cartTotal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        BeveragesMainActivity.cartTotal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    BeveragesMainActivity.cartTotal.setText(myPrefs.getInt("totalItems", 0) + "");
}

public void amount(int price){
    totalAmount = totalAmount+price;
    editor.putInt("totalAmount", totalAmount);
    editor.commit();
    BeveragesMainActivity.totalPrice.setText("Rs " + myPrefs.getInt("totalAmount", 0) + "");
}
}
```

Comment: "right now it is creating new object every time function is called" sure, there is a `new JSONObject()`! Keep that `jsonObject` as a class field and update its `quantity` then... Java 101 really...

Comment: i have tried that too. had declared JSONObject at the starting but still the same

Comment: -_- Post your edited code that does not work then, please...

Comment: please check the editted question :)

Comment: `obj` is JSONArray I guess. and you are adding objects to this array. please clarify..

Comment: yes obj is JSONArray and I am storing the objects in obj

Comment: `jsonObject.put("quantity",qty)` will not "add" anothing to `quantity` but will replace its value...

Comment: then what should i use instead of "put"

Answer (score 0):

Use this code inside `setCartItem(...)` method

```
    // loop through each object
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject item = obj.getJSONObject(i);
            int itemId = item.getInt("skuId ");
            if (itemId == skuId) {// object already exists update quantity
                item.put("quantity", qty);
                // update other keys if you want to
                // do other stuff
                return;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    // If skudId does not exits in the array list add new one
    try {

        jsonObject.put("skuId", skuId);
        jsonObject.put("quantity", qty);
        jsonObject.put("productId", productId);
        jsonObject.put("price", price);
        jsonObject.put("productName", productName);
        jsonObject.put("description", description);

        obj.put(jsonObject);
        editor.putString("data", obj.toString());
        editor.commit();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: still the same i mean still it is showing me 5 entries if quantity is 5

Comment: your unique key is `quantity` or `skuId`... above answer is related to this line from your question **only quantity should get updated if it is already there in json**

Comment: One sec. you will have only one json object or multiple objects.  clarify

Comment: i will have multiple json objects.

Comment: i am working on ecommerce app in which i am saving items selected in json which is later saved in sp and sending data to cart screen here what is happening is if i have selected frooti and quantity is 5 of skuId 1 then it is displaying 5 entries of frooti having skuId 1 and quantity is 5 for each entry

Comment: paste this code inside if (itemId == skuId) `editor.putString("data", obj.toString());
        editor.commit();`. Add above code don't keep duplicate values for `skuId`

Comment: I guess its not saving values in json as it is not displaying any thing

Comment: sorry cant help more. but  I am sure that above code stores only unique `skuId`s. loop through each object from Array you will come to know..